How to disable password authentication in SSH in Ubuntu 24.04 (new socket based SSH)
I'm in the process of hardening the security of a root VPS that runs Ubuntu 24.04. The recent Ubuntu versions use socket-based activation, and from my understanding, they don't execute the sshd_config file, so changing this file is useless. I want to keep using the socket-based activation for SSH, as it seems faster and consumes fewer resources than sshd
I found out how to change the port to a custom port which is hard to guess, but I can't seem to find how to disable password authentication (my server was previously hacked through an easy password, and I don't wish this to repeat).
Note: By password authentication, I mean disable SSH access with password, allowing only public/private key based authentication.

Do I understand correctly that you feel not having a password improves security?

@DavidDE I believe disabling SSH access through password (and allowing it only through public/private key) is a safer measure, Am I wrong ?

AFAIK socket based activation only affects the listening port setting - it's more likely that the password authentication setting is coming from somewhere else - such as an additional config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/. See for example Chages to sshd_config not disable password only login

This question is similar to: Why is "50-cloud-init.conf" created?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

From the implementation announcement:

On new installs of Ubuntu 22.10 or later, the OpenSSH change in behavior should be completely transparent to users.

sshd_config is still read, is still the place to enable key-based authentication, and is still the place to disable password-based authentication.
The only config changes required by socked-based sshd are for complex setups (Port and ListenAddress settings). How to handle those is also explained in the announcement.
Everything else remains the same.

"socket-based sshd" simply means that sshd is not running continuously. Instead, systemd monitors the port and then starts sshd when an inbound connection attempt is detected. sshd still runs, still handles authentication, and still uses sshd settings.


Oh I see, this is clearer now, thanks for the explanation.

+1 A very clear and concise answer.

As a retired computer security professional, I'd like to point out that changing the SSH port number only defends against novice hackers. Pros scan ports 1-65535, so we'll find it regardless.

Read man sshd_config, and add "PasswordAuthentication no" to /etc/sshd_config (hint man sudoedit), then restart sshd.
